# Why can't I import function from a class in the same directory?

Tags: python, pycharm

In my builder/graph_builder.py, I have a class

```
class GraphBuilder(object):

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  @staticmethod
  def parse(path):
     ...
     return path
```

Then in the same directory, I have a linker.py, and I want to import the 'parse' function:

```
 from builder.graph_builder.GraphBuilder import parse
```

I am in PyCharm and it prompts that 'from builder.graph_builder.' is visible, but after that, it can't reference GraphBuilder and parse function.

Why is that?

Comment: You cannot import functions from a class. You can import modules, and names in modules (although in that case, the whole module is still imported, just it isn't made available in the importing module's namespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is `from MODULE import NAME`, therefore

```
from builder.graph_builder import GraphBuilder
```

will work, but

```
from builder.graph_builder.GraphBuilder import parse
```

will not - `builder.graph_builder.GraphBuilder` is **not** a module.

Comment: after importing GraphBuilder you should be able to initialize an instance and call the  method from this instance:

gb = GraphBuilder(o); 
gp.parse(path)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to import a Method from a Class in python

You have to, first import the class and after call the method. It happen even if it is a static method.

Answer (score 1):

As graph_builder is located at same directory, you could refer graph_builder directly.

Furthermore GraphBuilder is a class, so you could instantiate and store parse function into a variable

You could try like this:

```
from graph_builder import GraphBuilder


if __name__=='__main__':
    path="C:\\Users\\"
    parse=GraphBuilder().parse
    test=parse(path)
```

Comment: I tested, I have to prefix 'graph_builder' with GraphBuilder; otherwise, it says it can't find it. Why is that? Is it a PyCharm problem?